# Access Token from Azure App without user Login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get AccessToken from Azure for my app.  and I have been trying from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) Section 4. unfortunately when i write below code to get the access token. It says Bad request. Here is my code which i am trying

```
string gUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/0000000000-49d7-9734-d930e2db05de/oauth2/v2.0/token";

string ss = "{"+
                              "\"client_id\": \"some Id of Client\","+
                              "\"scope\": \"https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default\"," +
                              "\"client_secret\": \"\"," +
                              "\"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\""+
                             
                          "}";

var payload = new StringContent(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ss).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

public static string GraphToken(string urlService,StringContent postValue)
        {
            try
            {
                string request = string.Empty;
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", token))));
                    using (HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), urlService) { Content = postValue })
                    {
                        var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
                        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            request = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                            Console.Write("success");
                            Console.ResetColor();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return request;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: You need to send those values as URL encoded form data, not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get access token without user login, you can use the code below, I think it's easier than call a http request in code.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp27
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("<client id>")
                .WithTenantId("<tenant id>")
                .WithClientSecret("<client secret>")
                .Build();

            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(authResult.AccessToken);
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to install this [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client) to run the code above.

Comment: Hi @Parth May I know if the code work ? If it works fine, could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: Sure. I am yet to try that out, Please bare with me for couple of hours.. i will update. Sorry for the delay